# vb.net programmatically creating controls

Tags: vb.net

I'm a beginner in vb.net programming and I'm slightly confused with creating controls.  It seems that when I'm online the following code I see is used interchangeably:

```
Dim x As Button
Dim y As New Button()
```

or even

```
Dim z As New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
```

Does it matter how I declare the variable? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.windows.forms.Button` is the same as declaring `Button`.  You just already have the `System.windows.forms` namespace imported. This is unless you have created your own button class in a different namespace, but I doubt you have.

The brackets after the name of the class will create an array of undefined size of that class.   No brackets is creating one instance of that class.

The `new` keyword is required when creating new instances of a control.  Without it, the variable you created will need to be assigned to an existing object of the same type.  Seeing as you are wanting to create buttons programmatically, you should use the `new` keyword.

Have a look at these tutorials for a basic introduction to creating classes 
http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/net/nets11p2.html
http://visualbasic.about.com/od/quicktips/qt/shared_member.htm

Comment: I got everything except the brackets.  What do you mean when you say "it creates an array of undefined size of that class".  dumb it down pretty please? :P

Comment: The brackets after the name of the class are NOT creating an array.  When you use the New keyword, you're initializing a new instance of that control.  This calls the default constructor for the control, which is defined as Public Sub New ().  The brackets after the name of the control are used to pass in any parameters to the constructor.  Since the button doesn't have any parameters being passed in, you are left with only the brackets.

Comment: @briddums Thanks for clearing that up, you are right regarfing the brackets, I was drunk lol

Answer (score 1):

This declares a variable of type Button called x. You cant use it until you assign something to it.

```
Dim x As Button
```

This instantiates a Button and assigns it to y. Gives yoiu a usable button "called" y

```
Dim y As New Button()
```

or even

This is the same as x, but uses a fully qualified name, for instance to to distinguish it from Jacob.Perkins.Button, if you had invented your own.

```
Dim z As New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
```

So yes it does matter.

When to use new, wehn you need to create (instantiate) one.

In .net

```
Dim x as Button
// followed by
x = new Button()
// is the same as
Dim x as new Button()
```

Dim x as button declares a variable called x that is expected to 'point to' an instance of Button.

if you said x = 36, you'd get a compiler error, because 36 isn't button it's a number. if you said x = Button1 and Button1 existed on say your form then that would be okay, given of course it was also a button.

At a certain point the only real way to "understand" this stuff it to start trying it.. Nothing horrible will happen, keep it simple and any mistakes you make will become obvious when you read the error message.

Comment: I'm still confused.  When would you use the "new" and "()" and when would you not want to use them.