# How to create multiple user controls with the same code at runtime in Vb.Net

Tags: vb.net

How can I use code similar to this to create multiple controls, I have been trying to figure this out for a while, but can't...

```
Dim newcontrol as control1 = New control1
Me.groupbox.controls.add(newcontrol)
```

Then add handlers, I want to name the controls like Visual Studio does it, newcontrol1, then newcontrol2, 3, etc... I don't know how many of these controls I will need, so it needs to add a new one whenever it is needed. Thanks in advance...

EDIT I am trying to do this at runtime, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: possible duplicate of [vb.net programmatically creating controls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8766849/vb-net-programmatically-creating-controls)

Comment: no, it is not a duplicate, I want to know hot to set a new control name based on a string that auto incraments whenever a new control is needed.

Comment: what difference does the name make? if it is added programatically, nothing but your code will see it; if it is a UC or custom control added to a form, VS will name it for you.

Comment: @Plitonix I am trying to set the contents of a string as the name of a control.

Comment: @Plutonix Tostring doesn't work, it says end of statement expected.

Comment: there is no way to create a control **reference** from a string - it would be creating a object variable from a variable. Since your code will be using the object created, it is more important where it is stored than what it is named.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55240/discussion-between-the-count-and-plutonix).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **cannot** create a control reference from a string variable:

```
Dim strVar As String = "MyControl"
...
For n As Integer = 0 To 3
    Dim thisVar As String = strVar &= n.Tostring

    thisVar = New NuControl    ' already declared as String,
                               ' cant ALSO be NuControl Type!
    ...
    theForm.Controls.Add(thisVar)
 Next n
```

How would your code ever keep track of such things?? `strVar/thisVar` is a variable and can change (vary) so you'd quickly loose track of them.  How would the compiler know how to handle it?  Would `thisVar = ""` reset the string or destroy the Control?

For dynamically added controls, you often need a way to track the ones added, especially when you dont know how many there will be. To create multiple user controls with the same code at runtime:

```
Dim btn As Button                     ' tmp var
Dim myBtns As New List(Of Buttons)    ' my tracker

' create 3 buttons:
For n As Integer = 0 To 3
    btn = New Button                  ' create a New button
    btn.Top = ...
    btn.Left = ...                    ' set props
    btn.Name = "Button" & n.ToString  

    AddHandler ....                   ' hook up any event handlers

    theForm.Controls.Add(btn)         ' add to form
    myBtns.Add(btn)                   ' add to my list
 Next n
```

What matter to the code is the ability to get at those controls we created, which is via an object reference.  To disable our buttons:

```
 For n As Integer = 0 to myBtns.Count - 1   ' could be 3, could be 103
     myBtns(n).Enabled = False
 Next n
```

Note that if the controls you create can be deleted on the fly as well, that **you** need to dispose of them properly should you remove them from the form since **you** created them.

Comment: Thanks, that helps, it looks like my problem was that I was doing: Dim btn As Button = New Button, instead of setting it later. Also, I realized I don't need to add an event handler, because everything is handled inside the control class.

Comment: `Dim btn As Button = New Button` will work, it is just not necessary to declare a new variable in a loop.  Even if the code for the handlers exists somewhere, you **will** need to hook up the new buttons to those handlers.